# "svn list" ignores externals

Tags: svn, list, ignore, externals

i have a directory called 'library' in my SVN tree which uses externals to load libs such as zend framework/smarty/....

im using a self written tool which uses "svn list" where i can select files which should be uploaded to the servers and it seems

svn list doesnt load external props and thus the library directory is empty
which means i cant upload the libs using my tool

so the question:
is there any option to have 'svn list' also load the externals?

thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution would be to call:

```
svn propget svn:externals -R
```

and call *svn list* on each external paths.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to [Francis B.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17067/francis-b), `svn list` may be enhanced in a future release of SVN, if I believe [this thread](http://svn.haxx.se/dev/archive-2009-08/0391.shtml):

> The list subcommand is excellent for writing scripts over the set of files/directories as listed in the repository, without having to fetch the source.
>
> I have been experimenting with using `svn:externals` leveraging the '`^`' syntax for describing logical views of my repository.
>
> However, I discovered that the `svn list` subcommand has no option for walking the externals. I think this would be a really useful feature to be able to list what would be checked out or exported without having to actually do it.
>
> Introducing an option such as `--no-ignore-externals` would allow the default for svn list to remain the same, but still allow the option to walk the externals.