# List a svn path that includes externals

Tags: list, svn, external

Note: This might be a duplicate of: ["svn list" ignores externals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346673/svn-list-ignores-externals)
If you deem it so please mark and close it.

Does SVN allow or have a tool for listing paths that include externals in them?

I am writing a tool to allow remote svn repositories to be handled as a filesystem, but currently trying to list a path with an external will show an error.

```
Example: 
> svn list svn://example.com/path/external/path 
svn: warning: W160013: URL svn://example.com/path/external/path' non-existent in revision 12345
svn: E200009: Could not list all targets because some targets don't exist
```

Currently I am using a workaround that works something similar to:

```
traversed = '';
while (file = path.next()) {
    if (svn.exists(file))
        traversed = path.join(traversed, file);
    else if(svn.externals(traversed).includes(file))
        traversed = path.join(traversed, file);  //Automatically normalizes path
    else
        throw; //An actually invalid path
}

//Here you can use 'traversed' as an actually valid path
```

But considering that I constantly need to request things from the server here, this will not scale well, especially if the internet connection becomes dodgy.

I have seen the post above, and it seems that back in 2007 they were planning to fix this, but so far I am unable to find neither a fix, nor a tool that would do this in a simpler way.

I am using CentOS with it's svn yum package (v1.12.2)

Edit: I need (when listing a path) for externals to act as symlinks. Meaning

```
svn list svn://example.com/path1/external/path3
should act same as
svn list svn://example.com/path2/actual_external_path/path3
```

Answer (score 0):

The `svn list` supports the `--include-externals` option. By default `svn list` does not display externals.

Comment: --include-externals will list the externals in a current directory you are listing, which is not what i need.
I need to be able to list with externals acting like symlinks. Please see the example path i gave.